# I can't redirect using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use Spring boot @scheduled to execute a task periodically. I want to redirect and jump to another page after the periodic execution of the task is completed. However, the process is executed periodically and the message is displayed, but the redirect is not performed.
Please advise me.

```
   enter code here  
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/index")
   public class TaskController {  
       @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
       public String task(){
              System.out.println("test");
              return "redirect:/index";
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

A method annotated with scheduled is running in your application without any interaction from the outside. So there is no client that could be redirected to anything.
You can only redirect from a method that is called because it is an mapped to a get or put or any other kind of request.